# Password Protected SQLite Database in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to make my SQLite database **password protected** in Windows 8 Store Application. How can I do this? I am unable to find a good way of doing it.

Comment: What do you mean by password protected ? Where should the password be asked while accessing it ?

Comment: When anyone try to access/open MyDatabase.sqlite file.

Comment: You can't do that, but you can encrypt that file. Check [my this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585654/Encypt-and-decrypt-StorageFile-in-Windows-Store-ap) If you find it fine, I will post it as answer and you please mark it as accepted.